# Image resizing function not running

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a python method that is supposed to resize an image

```
def Reformat_Image(ImageFilePath,fileName,image):
    print("inside Reformat_Image")
    image_size = image.size
    width = image_size[0]
    print
    height = image_size[1]
    if(width != height):
        bigside = width if width > height else height
        background = Image.new('RGBA', (bigside, bigside), (255, 255, 255, 255))
        offset = (int(round(((bigside - width) / 2), 0)), int(round(((bigside - height) / 2),0)))
        background.paste(image, offset)
        background.save(fileName+"Resized.jpg")
        print("Image has been resized")
```

and when I call to use it

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
        print("Resizing picture")
        Reformat_Image(ImageFilePath =image_path,fileName=fileName,image=image)
```

The inside of the `Reformat_Image()` method never runs. I am able to successfully open the image a few lines before that code is ran so I think my file names/ locations should be working fine.

Command prompt output:

```
> Resizing picture
```

Expected output:

```
> Resizing picture
> inside Reformat_Image
```

Comment: How are you running your code? — it looks like there should be some error messages. Please [edit] your question and provide and complete [mre] (and any errors that are occurring).

Comment: i suggest you to use opencv libary to resize image and use code (cv2.resize) on opencv

Comment: Would this let me add a background to it? This is for resizing images to post things onto Instagram and it has to be within a certain aspect ratio and I don’t want to cut off the image to do it

Comment: I am running it with the command prompt. When I would run it I would get no output, its weird for some reason my code does not want to call upon the helper method. When I run the code for resizing by itself it works but when I put it inside its own method it does not jump to the inside of the method.  There is no output stating what is going on when this is happening.

Comment: Try calling it without specifying the argument names, i.e.: `Reformat_Image(image_path, fileName, image)`